# SAS Filename exceeds 32 characters

Tags: sas, filenames, proc-sql

I have multiple files in `.cpt` format.
These filenames exceed 32 characters and cannot be imported into sas using data step.

```
# ERROR

Filename file "path/&FILENAME..cpt "  ;
       
PROC CIMPORT INFILE = file LIBRARY = WORK ;
RUN;

data test;
    set &FILENAME.;
run;
```

I tried `proc sql` but getting stuck.

```
%macro test(FILENAME= );

        Filename file "path/&FILENAME..cpt "  ;
       
        PROC CIMPORT INFILE = file LIBRARY = WORK ;
        RUN;
        proc sql;
            create table test as 
            (
            select * from &FILENAME.
            );
        quit;
    
%MEND;

%test(FILENAME = filename_exceeds_thirtytwo_characters_1);
```

```
ERROR: Member name "filename_exceeds_thirtytwo_characters_1" exceeds 32 characters
```

Any help?

Comment: Knowing the `proc cport` executed to create the file would help to understand how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file used to store the CPORT file does not necessarily have anything to do with the name(s) of any datasets that might be contained in the CPORT file.

To see what members (if any) are in the CPORT file check the notes generated by your PROC CIMPORT step.

Since you told PROC CIMPORT to write the datasets to the WORK library your DATA or PROC SQL steps are not needed.

Also do not append an extra space on the end of the filename.

```
PROC CIMPORT INFILE = "/somepath/&FILENAME..cpt" LIBRARY = WORK ;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the log information that `Proc CIMPORT` creates.

Your problem is the `from` clause in the `Proc SQL` `select` statement

```
select * from &FILENAME.
```

You are using the long filename as the table to select from.  SAS table names (also known as library member names) are limited to 32 characters.  So there is your error.

After you `Proc CIMPORT` the data sets to `WORK`, what are the table names ?  If you look in the log the procedure will list the members it imported.

- Are any of the members listed the same name as the filename ?  Probably not.
- Do any of the members listed have sequential suffixes and clipped at <32 character prefixes ? Extreme edge case, maybe.  *Some* SAS procedures have a best-try naming algorithm when it has to create multiple >32 character member names in the same library.

Comment: Yes the dataset name was truncated. For example, assume original file name `in_FILENAMELONG_XXXX.cpt` is longer than 32 characters. It cut to `FILENAMELONG_XXXX.cpt`. But the issue comes out! How can I scan the Macro name: `%LET Newname = %scan(&FILENAME., 4)`